# Get a file system handle to a bluetooth mapped folder

Tags: windows, filesystems, bluetooth

Is there any way to get code level access to a bluetooth mapped drive?  The simple use case is I have a bluetooth folder in Explorer that looks something like:

"My Bluetooth Places\Entire Bluetooth Neighborhood\DEV1\OBEX File Transfer\E:\"

which maps to a device root, and I want to be able to read/write to the file system by treating it as a standard directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  The way to achieve this is to open a Bluetooth serial connection to the device in question, and traverse its file system using the [OBEX File Transfer profile](https://obex4j.dev.java.net/files/documents/2519/9269/OBEX13.pdf).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

What you see in the explorer is the string representation of PIDL — a list of identifiers.

You should study COM as technology, then Shell extensions.

For what you see in the Explorer, is a virtual 'file' system. The bluetooth software extends it.

Here is a door: [IShellFolder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775075(VS.85).aspx) interface. Note, that it is not the best place to start learning.